# How to set current build result in Jenkins Pipeline according to the execution result?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I wrote the following code and want to send email notification to user. However I noticed that sometimes there are "false positive" reports. I just wonder if there is a way Jenkins declarative pipeline allow me use the real execution status to set currentBuild.result. (I guess I should use `currentBuild.result = 'SUCCESS'` or `'FAILURE'`). For example, `start_up.sh /mydata/test.json` could write either 'SUCCESSFUL' or 'ERROR' to a file. How can I set currentBuild.result to 'SUCCESS' or  'FAILURE', respectively, according to the content of that file? Thanks a lot.

```
pipeline {

  agent {
    docker {
      image ...
      args ...
    }
  }

  parameters {
    string(name: 'E_USERNANE', defaultValue: 'githubuser', description: 'Please input the username')
    string(name: 'E_BRANCH', defaultValue: 'dev', description: 'Please input the git branch you want to test')
  }

  stages {
    stage('build') {
      steps {
        echo "username: ${params.E_USERNANE}"
        echo "branch: ${params.E_BRANCH}"
        sh """
        ...
        start_up.sh /mydata/test.json
        ...
        """
      }
    }
  }

  post {
    failure {
      // notify users when the Pipeline fails
      mail to: 'xxxi@gmail.com',
      subject: "Failed Pipeline * ${currentBuild.fullDisplayName}",
      body: "Something is wrong with ${env.BUILD_URL}."
    }
    success {
      // notify users when the Pipeline succeeds
      mail to: 'xxx@gmail.com',
      subject: "Success Pipeline * ${currentBuild.fullDisplayName}",
      body: "The build ${env.BUILD_URL} is passed!"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the Title (*How to set current build result in Jenkins Pipeline according to the execution result?*) is a bit different from the code sample (*How can I set currentBuild.result to 'SUCCESS' or 'FAILURE', respectively, according to the content of that file?*)

In declarative pipeline like yours, current build (and stage) result can easily be set depending on the command execution results using `catchError` block. E.g. to set the stage as `FAILURE` and the overall job as `UNSTABLE`:

```
catchError(buildResult: 'UNSTABLE', stageResult: 'FAILURE') {
    command ...
}
```

I'm not aware of an elegant one-liner for setting the build/stage results directly from the file content (question from the Body). But I guess you can (and should) set the right exit code of your `start_up.sh` script when writing the status message to the file. So when writing `"SUCCESSFUL"` to the file you can exit the script with zero code, but when writing `"ERROR"` you can exit with non-zero code instead. That would be sufficient for the pipeline to work with `catchError` block as explained above.

Answer (score -3):

Here is a sample I am using in some projects with gitlab integration ...but using scripted pipeline.
There is email notification available when build fails, and when it comes back stable.

```
/* documentation pour les appels gitlab:
 https://github.com/jenkinsci/gitlab-plugin#configuring-access-to-gitlab



    node {
    try {
 
        stage('Deploy') {
            gitlabCommitStatus("Deploy") {
             ...    
        }
       }
   
    }
         currentBuild.result = 'SUCCESS'

    } // try
    catch(all) {
        echo "failures"
        currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'
        notifyFailed()
    }
    finally {

        if (currentBuild.getPreviousBuild().result == 'FAILURE') {
         if (currentBuild.result == 'SUCCESS') {
                echo 'build has been fixed'
                notifyFixed()
            }
        }
    } 
    echo "RESULT: ${currentBuild.result}"

}


def notifyFixed()
{
    emailext (
            subject:"[Integration Continue] ${env.JOB_NAME} - Compilation # ${env.BUILD_NUMBER} - Build has been fixed",
            body:"""
            <p>Compilation fixed par commit ${env.GIT_COMMIT}

            "<a href="${env.BUILD_URL}">${env.JOB_NAME} [${env.BUILD_NUMBER}]</a>"
            </p>
            """,
            recipientProviders:[[$class: 'DevelopersRecipientProvider'],[$class: 'CulpritsRecipientProvider']]
            )

}

def notifyFailed() {
    emailext (
            subject:"[Integration Continue] ${env.JOB_NAME} - Compilation # ${env.BUILD_NUMBER} - FAILED:",
            body:"""
            <p>
            Commit ${env.GIT_COMMIT} 
            Vérifier la sortie de la console pour voir le résultat de la compilation :
            "<a href="${env.BUILD_URL}">${env.JOB_NAME} [${env.BUILD_NUMBER}]</a>"
            </p>
            """,
            recipientProviders:[[$class: 'DevelopersRecipientProvider'],[$class: 'CulpritsRecipientProvider']]
            )
}
```

Comment: So much of this answer is just noise. Would it be possible to cut it down to the point?